# How to make @CreatedBy and @CreatedDate non modifiable in Spring data jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I am using simple crud operations with auditing in spring data jdbc. so when ever i insert new record auditing works absolutely fine. but when i am updating my record my createdby and createddate setting to null. is there any way i can avoid modifying these columns?

Note:spring data jdbc is not supported with column(updatable= false) feature.

My audit entity looks like below:

```
@Data // lombak
public class AuditEntity {
  @JsonIgnore
  @LastModifiedDate
  private String updatedOn;
  @JsonIgnore
  @LastModifiedBy
  private String updatedBy;
  @JsonIgnore
  @CreatedDate
  private String createdBy;
  @JsonIgnore
  @CreatedBy
  private String createdOn;

}
```

and for configuration using @EnableJdbcAuditing and defining the below bean

```
@Bean
  AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
    return new CustomAuditAware();
  }
```

my custom audit aware looks like below

```
public class CustomAuditAware implements AuditorAware {
  @Override
  public Optional getCurrentAuditor() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(
        "System");
  }
}
```

Comment: what database  are you using?

Comment: using Mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as far as I know it is not possible. Since MySQL doesn't restrict the change of a data in any column.

However, developers make a use of [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Triggers basically help you record, observe and validate any change of data(database row).

```
create trigger check_if_a_column_has_changed on your_table
-- before update
   pull your old column value and check if it has been changed, 
   throw error if data been changed
```

Catch this exception in your application and show error messages to your clients.

Study database triggers, they will help you. However you'll have to bear the cost of a little bit of lag as the data in your table grows.

Comment: instead of throwing an exception it should be possible to replace null values with whatever is already in the table.

Comment: Through triggers we can achieve but I am looking into spring way... At least is there any events in spring data jdbc to update this created by with old value only?

Comment: Well in that case, just before updating the entity, why don't you Query the old record from database and check for the corresponding fields and take appropriate actions?

Comment: thats my final option. i am just checking for any common place that we can change this data. since in my above example i am not adding these values myself... spring takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

To help others who are still looking,

Alternate way to make a field insertable only (like audit fields: createdDate & createdBy) in **spring-data-JDBC**, is to use **@InsertOnlyProperty**

So the properties in original question would become like:

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedDate
    @InsertOnlyProperty
    private String createdBy;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedBy
    @InsertOnlyProperty
    private String createdOn;
```

Reference Link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/pull/1327

Answer (score 1):

To help others who are still looking,

You can also have the `updatable` property from the `@Column` to `false`.

```java
  @CreatedDate
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private Instant createdAt;
```

Comment: i am asking for spring data jdbc, updatable not available here